# @ManyToOne UniDirectional delete

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, many-to-one

I have a @ManyToOne Uni-directional relationship between person and car, meaning a car can be owned by several persons. The problem is when I delete a car, the car id's is not deleted from the Person's entity join-column. Is there a way to configure JPA to remove car id's from the owner person join-column after deleting a car?

**Note:**
Using orpahRemoval=true will not help, since I need to update the parent's car reference to null, and each entity (Car / Person) is not dependent on the existence of the other...

```
 @Entity
    public class Car{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private long id;
    }

    @Entity
    public class Person {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private long id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="CAR_ID")
        private Car car;  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No. You'll need to execute a query to find all the persons with the given car, set their car to null, then delete the car:

```
List<Person> persons = em.createQuery("select p from Person p where p.car = :car", Person.class)
                         .setParameter("car", car)
                         .getResultList();
for (Person person : persons) {
    person.setCar(null);
}
em.remove(car);
```